# "Object.values" não retorna valor de uma chave "Symbol". Como resolver?

Tags: javascript, objetos

Podemos usar o método `Object.values` para retornar os valores de um objeto:

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'Cardeal',
  age: 29
}

const values = Object.values(obj)

console.log('[OBJ]: ', obj)
console.log('[VALUES]: ', values)
```

O problema é que se neste objeto, se alguma chave for definida com um `Symbol` (`name` por exemplo), `Object.values` não retorna o correspondente valor desta chave:

```js
const name = Symbol('name')

const obj = {
  [name]: 'Cardeal',
  age: 11
}

const values = Object.values(obj)

console.log('[OBJ]: ', obj)
console.log('[VALUES]: ', values)
```

Tentar transformar o objeto em JSON e depois desserializar não funciona também por causa do tipo da chave.

É possível contornar isso e retornar o valor de uma chave `Symbol` dentro do objeto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece pois `Object.values` retorna dados enumeráveis `[chave, valor]`.

Veja a [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

> `Object.values()` retorna um array cujos elementos são os valores das propriedades enumeradas encontradas no objeto.

Este mesmo problema vai ocorrer se tentar outros métodos como `Object.entries`:

```js
const name = Symbol('name')

const obj = {
  [name]: 'Cardeal',
  age: 11
}

// não vai retornar ["name", "Cardeal"]
console.log(Object.entries(obj))
```

O correto para retornar o valor dessa chave `Symbol`, é usar o método `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()` e manipular esta com um `map` para retornar os valores.

Sobre este método na [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols):

> O `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()` método retorna uma array com todas propriedades de símbolo encontradas diretamente em um determinado objeto dado.

```js
const name = Symbol('name')

const obj = {
  [name]: 'Cardeal',
  age: 11
}

// Vai retornar um array de tamanho 1, pois temos 1 Symbol
console.log('[SYMBOL COUNT]', Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj).length)

// usando um "map" para retornar o valor do Symbol "name", através do "obj[sym]"
const symbolValues = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj).map(sym => obj[sym])

// retornar o valor "Cardeal"
console.log('[SYMBOL VALUES]', symbolValues)
```

Podemos criar uma função que combine o uso de `Object.entries` e `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()` para retornar todos os valores de um objeto.

Exemplo bem simples para demonstrar:

```js
const name = Symbol('name')
const other = Symbol('other')

const obj = {
  [name]: 'Cardeal',
  [other]: '00000-000',
  age: 11,
  other: 'any'
}

const getAllValues = (obj = {}) => {
  const symbolValues = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj).map(sym => obj[sym])
  const values = Object.values(obj)
  return [...symbolValues, ...values]
}

console.log(getAllValues(obj))
```

##### `Object.fromEntries()` [ES2019]

Sobre este método, ele funciona da seguinte maneira: Dado um iterável como `[chave, valor]`, este retorna um objeto:

```js
const newObj = Object.fromEntries(
    [
      ['age', 29]
    ]
 )
 
console.log(newObj)
```

Ou seja, `Object.fromEntries()` faz o oposto de `Object.entries()`, mas tem um detalhe, `Object.fromEntries()` não ignora o tipo `Symbol`:

```js
const name = Symbol('Cardeal')
const newObj = Object.fromEntries(
  [
    ['age', 29],
    [name, 'Cardeal']
  ]
)

// vai exibir o valor de "name" - "Cardeal"
console.log(newObj[name])
```

---

Links úteis:

- [JavaScript for impatient programmers (ES2022 edition)](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_objects.html#Object.fromEntries)
- [MDN Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)